# Keras-Tuner parallel processing using multi-core CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-tuner

I am currently running a hyperparameter search in Keras-Tuner using GridSearch. I wanted to get some clarification on whether or not Keras-Tuner can utilize multiple CPU cores/threads to speed up the process of Hyperparameter tuning. I know there is documentation online about utilizing multiple GPUs via tf.distribute, but I am specifically interested in utilizing my Threadripper PRO 3975WX and NVIDIA RTX A6000.

To verify, when I run the top command in the terminal during the hyperparameter search, it only shows one process for Python running. I know that when using alternatives, such as scikit, configuring the n_jobs parameter before a search creates multiple python processes running together.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.